# Get elements in common from array of arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

Let's say I have an array like this one:

```
[
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [3, 4, 5, 6],
  [4, 5, 6, 8]
]
```

I need to get the elements in common between them all. How can I achieve that?

The result should be

```
 common_elements([[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6, 8]]) # => [4]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6, 8]].reduce(:&) # => [4]
```

The [Array#&](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-26) method gives you set intersection:

```
[1, 2, 3] & [2, 3, 4] # => [2, 3]
```

The [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) method can combine the values in given array using an operation:

```
[1, 2, 3].reduce(:+) # => 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it "manually lol"... You do each to iterate  of over the nested arrays `[[0],[1],[2]],` then you iterate over each nested array and use include 
ary[pos].include?(x) with AND between all three nested arrays to find intersecting value, It will be slow, but handy if you want to add more conditions .

```
 user> ary = [ [1,2,3,4], [3,4,5,6], [4,5,6,8] ]
 => [[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6, 8]] 

user> ary.each { |f| f.each {|x| 
                 puts "#{x}"  if ary[0].include?(x) && ary[1].include?(x) &&  
                 ary[2].include?(x)  }} 
4
4
4
```

or simply,

```
2.1.2 :003 > ary = [ [1,2,3,4], [3,4,5,6], [4,5,6,8] ].inject(:&)
 => [4]
```

Comment: Don't write code like `[a=[1,2,3,4], b=[3,4,5,6], c=[4,5,6,8] ]`. It's a maintenance nightmare and definitely not recommended or idiomatic.

Comment: I agree @  the Tin Man  , I have changed the answer to not include the a=,b=,c= blah...

Comment: Now try to do it without using `include?' repeatedly. Imagine if the arrays increased to 100 times their size and the performance dropped to a crawl as a result.